# Manipulating CSV file with bash and remove CR LF in specific column

Tags: bash, csv, parsing, awk

I have a file that's generated by a vendor. This vendor refuses to strip out the CR LF in the middle of some data due to how they concatenate two lines together in the file. The result is manual effort to identify and clean up these instances.

What I'd like to do is for each line in this file, if there is a CR LF in the 6th spot in the record- then remove it and replace it with a space. Here's an example with one in the 6th spot that I need to parse out. The file has 1-2 million lines and only a dozen or so have the CR LF in the 6th spot of the record. There's also a CR LF at the end of each record, so I can't just replace every instance of CR LF in the file.

```
XXXXXX~XXXXXX~XXXXXX~XXXXXX~~-NEW CUSTOMER HANK BUDREAU
DL:WD-XX-XX5
CONF# 12344564 ~XXXXXX~XXXXXX~XXXXXX~KWH~~000015~16~10132022074500PM~10~0.0798~10~0.0582~10~0.0606~10~0.0666~10~0.8358~10~1.5564~10~1.0986~10~0.6048~10~0.2022~10~0.0372~10~0.045~10~0.0318~10~0.0366~10~0.036~10~0.0294~10~0.0672~
```

Comment: It looks like `~` is the field separator, true?

Comment: 2 blocks of sample input would be vastly more useful for testing with than 1. Also add the expected output.

Comment: their CSV is invalid; quoting is mandatory when a field contains a LF

Comment: Yes Glenn - ~ is the separator. Ed - I'll add another line that looks good as an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the number of fields in advance (47 here) then you can use something like this:

```bash
awk -F '~' -v nFields=47 '
    NF < nFields {
        if (nf) {
            rec = rec "\n" $0
            if (NF)
                nf += NF - 1
        } else {
            rec = $0
            nf = (NF ? NF : 1)
        } 
        if ( nf >= nFields ) {
            gsub(/\r\n/," ",rec)
            print rec
            nf = 0
        }
        next
    }
    1
'
```

<sup>**notes:** The above code doesn't work if the last field is the one that contains a `LF`.</sup>